# How Jetpack Compose determine to do recomposition or not?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Click doesn't trigger a recomposition in the code below:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    println("ExampleScreen()")
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            count++
        },
        content = {
            Text(text = "Click Me!")
        }
    )
}
```

Click triggers a recomposition by just add an expression `count` in the code below:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    println("ExampleScreen()")
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    count // only difference

    Button(
        onClick = {
            count++
        },
        content = {
            Text(text = "Click Me!")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: read this https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose and the part1 and 2 here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-jetpack-compose-part-1-of-2-ca316fe39050. it is recomposing cause you are reading count in the compose scope in the 2nd example

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan. I've just read the 3 articles and I found they are so interesting especially the last one.

Comment: I want to know how Compose determines whether the 'count' is to be read or not. Does the compiler determine it and set the return value of '$composer.end()' accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

Compose triggers a recomposition if the input parameters to a composable have changed, based on equality.

In your code here

```
@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    println("ExampleScreen()")
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            count++
        },
        content = {
            Text(text = "Click Me!")
        }
    )
}
```

nothing is reading the state `count`, so nothing recomposes when `count` changes. If you were to change it like this

```
@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    println("ExampleScreen()")
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                count++
            },
            content = {
                Text(text = "Click Me!")
            }
        )
        Text(
            text = "Clicked $count times"
        )
    }
}
```

where `count` is read on the `Text` composable, then that composable will recompose when `count` changes.